# Makefile - what does ">" mean?

Tags: bash, makefile

i am trying to learn this Book: "Managing Projects with GNU Make".
there is an example with this Makefile:

```
count_words: count_words.o lexer.o -lfl
    gcc counter_words.o lexer.o -lfl -o count_words

count_words.o: count_words.c
    gcc -c count_words.c

lexer.o: lexer.c
    gcc -c lexer.c

lexer.c: lexer.l
    flex -t lexer.l > lexer.c
```

i totally dont understand this line

```
flex -t lexer.l > lexer.c
```

what does the character ">" mean in this case? And what is .l ?

Comment: It means "write the output of `flex -t lexer.l` to the file `lexer.c`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an [output redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29). It means the output of the `flex -t lexer.l` command will be written in the file `lexer.c` .

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I have to answer.
I want to address the .l part,
The .l files are the sources for flex that generate .c files

The `>` is a output redirector. See Miklos' answer for more on that.

Comment: Thanks you too for the fast help :) ! Thats helps me a lot